# How to animate objects without flickering

Tags: javascript, json, animation, setinterval, fabricjs

Please help! I'm using Fabric js to create an app which I want to be able to create animations of objects.

At the minute I'm adding the object movement (JSON) to an array and then using set interval to replay.

Is there a better way of doing this? I can't use images in these animations because they flicker.

Thanks..

```
$("#startAnimation").click(function(){
                  console.log(JSON);

        canvas.on(
        'object:modified', function () {

        addToAnim(true);
    },
        'object.moving', function () {
        addToAnim(true);
    });

   });


    function addToAnim(saveAnim) {
        if (saveAnim === true) {
            animJSON = JSON.stringify(canvas);
            animArray.push(animJSON);
        }
    }


    $("#animate").click(function(){
    playAnimation();
    });

        function playAnimation(){
        var animLength = animArray.length;
        var animateCanvas = setInterval(function(){
            canvas.clear().renderAll();
            canvas.loadFromJSON(animArray[animIndex++]);
          canvas.renderAll();

            if(animIndex >= animArray.length){
                animIndex = 0;      
                clearInterval(animateCanvas);
            //animIndex = (animIndex + 1) % animLength;


            }
        }, 50);
```

Comment: Hey, could you maybe use jsfiddle to add your html and css

Comment: @nfnneil thanks for the reply! Sorry, I haven't used it before. I gave it a go but it's not working. https://jsfiddle.net/q9qgnd8u/4/
Just to clarify - my animation is working but I think it's probably horrible on memory and like I said I'd like the option to somehow animate images too, but the way I'm doing it now the images flicker while being loaded. Thanks

Comment: I tried to fix some of the easy JS errors in your fiddle (you are missing closing braces and parens at the end) but then I started getting other errors. Maybe take a look there and see if you can clean it up to get it working before people can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/edboe0v5/1/

Comment: So you are using a complete canvas restore from JSON to make an animation. This is heavyer than necessary if you know your animation. The flicker come from fabric clenaning the canvas and then redrawing stuff over it. While this can be fixed, you should look in fabric.animate

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi do you know how I could isolate the json for the individual objects that are being animated? I've only started learning JavaScript in the last month or so I really have no idea how to go about this.